# Understanding the abrupt beginning and the pre-plot of Infinity War

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

The movie Avengers: Infinity Wars starts from the end of Thor: Ragnarok. So we assume that Thor and the remaining Asgardians find Thanos's spaceship approaching them and Thanos attacks the entire ship. The scene starts off with the only survivors being Thor, Loki and Heimdall facing Thanos and his children.

At the same time the Guardians of the Galaxy seem to be coursing towards Thor/Grandmaster's vessel and Quill mentions that they received a distress signal. I would like to have some explanation of how the three worlds meet :Thor's + Thanos + GOG .
what was the pre plot of these three worlds before Infinity War begins?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here. Is this about a part in the story that you missed somehow? Or are you actually asking for the exact details of the story *before* the events we were shown in the film? With the former I'm sure a proper summary can help you more and the latter I'm afraid seems to be beyond our capabilities of knowing. But feel free to provide a little more context as what part of the story was unclear to you.

Answer (score 14):

**Thanos**

- After the end of Avengers: Age of Ultron, picks up an Infinity Gauntlet and declares "Fine, I'll do it myself".

  > Heads to Xandar, destroys the planet, and picks up the Power Stone.
- In some way, senses the locations of the Space Stone/Tesseract. He may have simply been on route to Asgard - the last known location.
- Finds the Asgardian ship as the refugees are fleeing the ruins of Asgard, planning to head to Earth (Thor: Ragnarok).

  > Boards and slays (between Thor:Ragnaok, and Infinity War).

**Thor**

- Asgard is in ruins.
- Wants to head to Earth, and is thinking about where his people will resettle.
- Encounters a Thanos (Thor: Ragnarok).

  > Fights as his ship is being boarded, and his people are being slain by the Black Order (between Thor:Ragnaok, and Infinity War). A distress signal is sent.

**Guardians of the Galaxy**

- Cruising through space (before Infinity War).

> Receive a distress signal from the Asgardian ship (Infinity War). Choose whether to respond or not based on the possibility of $$$ reward. Which of course isn't important.

That's the gist of the details revealed through the movie, and previous end-credits scenes.

Comment: I think it makes more sense for that part with Thanos saying "Fine, I'll do it myself" to take place after Guardians of the Galaxy since Xandar was still intact (sort of) by that time and it was probably Ronan's failure that really pushed Thanos over the edge.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I think it's _Guardians of the Galaxy 2_ not the first _Guardians of the Galaxy_ that OP is talking about.

Comment: @KodosJohnson The scene was part of the end-credits of Avengers: Age of Ultron. It almost definitely happened after Guardians of the Galaxy movie as well (which is how the Power Stone came to Xandar). By this point Thanos has given the Mind Stone to Loki, failed to get the Tessert (Avengers), failed to get the Soul Stone (Gamora), and failed to get the Power Stone (Guardians). We are seeing the Guardians in this movie after the events of Guardians of the Galaxy 2, and they don't know about the eventual fate of Xandar at this point.

Comment: Ah ok, you said only Avengers before your edit so I thought you meant the first one.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yeah figured I'd clarify. I think mentally I was thinking "the last Avengers one"